# Regarding Date issue in Excel

Tags: string, excel, date

I have issue on my Date field in Excel. Format is like this "2016-07-15T14:07:08.000Z". I tried to convert it into like this "15/07/2016 14:07:08".
Help plzz

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn the string into something Excel will recognize as a time stamp, and then format it accordingly.

eg:

```
=TEXT(--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," "),"Z",""),"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

or, for a "real" date-time and not a text string:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," "),"Z","")
```

and custom format the cell the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a combination of Left and Mid functions to extract the text values and plug them into Date() and Time() functions. Like this (my regional settings are DMY):

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))+
TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),MID(A1,18,2))
```

[image]

Comment: I applied this formula, it gives me the date alone not time.

Comment: What is the cell value? Post it here.